# Getting build error ios while uploading zip file in phonegap

Tags: ios, windows, certificate, phonegap

I am a windows user with no access to ios. I am also new to phonegap.
 How to add signing keys for ios and certificate in it as i wish to build and run the same.
And how to make our phongap apps public its private now.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this link below. It is for how you generate all those certificatesigning, cer, p12, mobileprovision, and pem. Yes, the most important file you need is p12 and mobileprovision. But before you can get those 2, you need to generate certificatesigning,cer, and pem. Remember your app ID and password is important while you generate those file. Don't ever lost it. Later on if you try to upload the IPA file to itunes, you can try appsuploader require to pay for subscription, but cheap price and it is for windows user.

https://www.joshmorony.com/how-to-create-an-ios-provisioning-profile-and-p12-with-windows/